# calling js namesapce funcitons from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As it is evident from below question I am new to html/js and forgive me if this question was asked previously.

All I am trying to do is call a js function defined in namespace from html and I cannot get this to work.

When I click on "Alert!!" button, it should invoke myAlert function defined in sample.js file, but it is not working..Can you help me please?

Here is my sample.js file..

```
var mytest = mytest || {};
(function ($) {
    function youhere() {
        alert("You are Here!!");
    }
    function myAlert() {
        alert("YouMadeIt");
    }
    function funcInit() {
        youhere();
    }
    mytest.funcInit = funcInit;    
}(jQuery));
```

And html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Sample</TITLE>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/sample.js"></script>
    </HEAD>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            mytest.funcInit();
        });
        function testBtnClk() {
            mytest.myAlert();
        }        
    </script>
    <BODY>        
        <input type="button" id="testbtn" onclick="testBtnClk();" value="Alert!!" />
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `myAlert` is not a property of `mytest`.

The function `myAlert` is a closure function which exists only inside the IIFE, it is not accessible outside of that IIFE. Since you have a global namespace you can add the function reference to that so that you can use that reference to call the method outside of the IIFE.

```
var mytest = mytest || {};
(function ($) {
    function youhere() {
        alert("You are Here!!");
    }

    function myAlert() {
        alert("YouMadeIt");
    }

    function funcInit() {
        youhere();
    }
    mytest.funcInit = funcInit;
    mytest.myAlert = myAlert;
}(jQuery));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8y19coru/)

Comment: Thanks!! That worked..I tried a similar approach before, but it was automatically invoking myAlert() function..it could be that I defined this inside ready function..Thanks for your help!!